# Problems with sessions in symfony2

Tags: symfony

Faced with such a problem : when i click Add in the basket, I redirect to the `basket_action`, but a product that I have added is not displayed. It's my action

```
 /**
 * @Route("/basket", name="basket_action")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return mixed
 */
public function basketAction(Request $request)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();
    if(!$session->has('basket_action'))
    {
        $session->set('basket_action', array());
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $products = $em->getRepository('ModelBundle:Products')
        ->findArray(array_keys($session->get('basket_action')));  

    return $this->render("CoreBundle:Basket:basket.html.twig",
        array(
            'products' => $products,
            'basket' => $session->get('basket')
        ));
}
```

What am i doing wrong. Please, help.

Comment: Are you saving the session in your previous action before you redirect?

Comment: Where exactly? I am a little do not understand what you mean...

Comment: but where do you set basket_action beside  if(!$session->has('basket_action'))?

Comment: @Evgeniy Kuzmin Could you give an example that I understood. I would be grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hart to give you any example, cause it looks like you missed some code or logic. From what I can see in

```
$session = $request->getSession();
if(!$session->has('basket_action'))
{
    $session->set('basket_action', array());
}
```

you just try to analize, is 'basket_action' stored to session, if not then assign it with an empty array. But were do you suppose to set "basket_action" with real data?

so if you has it at some other action, pls show this code too, if no, then you should add setter to session with filled data for 'basket_action'

**Update:**

Ok, I see that seems you missed some logic at the code

It is still hard to guess what exactly you need, but If it is expected to add every new product by clicking "Add" and pickup all old added products from session, then it will looks like something:

```
/**
 * @Route("/basket", name="basket_action")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return mixed
 */
public function basketAction(Request $request)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $cartIds = $session->get('basket_action', array());
    $cartIds[] = $request->query->get('id');
    $session->set('basket_action', $cartIds);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $products = $em->getRepository('ModelBundle:Products')
        ->findArray($cartIds);  

    return $this->render("CoreBundle:Basket:basket.html.twig",
        array(
            'products' => $products,
        ));
}
```

P.S. sorry I can't know what you are suppose to get from $session->get('basket')", cause I don't see what did you store there, so I just deleted "'basket' => $session->get('basket')" from template params

Comment: it's my temlate http://i.piccy.info/i9/7f004e3a4baae9f6b384c66f197a2e5a/1431290682/27468/907262/Screenshot_2.jpg

Comment: Repository http://i.piccy.info/i9/886e3a6d4438243cbbdf130047d04e9b/1431290724/16927/907262/Screenshot_1.jpg

Comment: basket.html.twig
http://i.piccy.info/i9/c94fad568ab4131f25c86988319cd815/1431290837/13834/907262/Screenshot_3.jpg

Comment: When i after `findArray(array_keys($session->get('basket_action')));` do `var_dump($products)` and `die()` i have `NULL`

Comment: sure, because you didn't store the ids to session, will update my answer with some code example